# Numpy: "<<" and ">>" operators

Tags: python, numpy

I was doing some Numpy exercises and came across this example:

```
z = np.arange(10)
2 << z
```

It outputs:
    array([   2,    4,    8,   16,   32,   64,  128,  256,  512, 1024])

There are a few other operators like this for example: z >> 2, z <- z, z >- z

I did a search and surprisingly found nothing on Google.

Can anyone explain what these operators do? Any documentations?

Comment: There is no `<-` or `>-`. There is `> (-z)` and `< (-z)` perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operators `<<` and `>>` are bit shift operators (left and right, respectively). In your particular example (with `<<`), you are performing `x = x * 2^z` for each array element, resulting in your modified output. The operator `>>` in the same example would yield an output characterized by `x = x / 2^z` for each array element.

As mentioned earlier, `<-X` is the same as `< (-X)` (and vice versa for `>-`); these are not defined Python operators.

Answer (score 0):

> I did a search and surprisingly found nothing on Google

The << operator can be used as a shorthand for np.left_shift on ndarrays:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.left_shift.html